# Getting ALL picture file names from wikimedia commons search

Tags: python, image, wikimedia-commons

So I'm trying to get all the picture files names for a wikimedia image search, but I'm only getting 10 results.

As an example, I tried running:

```
import json
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib.request
import requests
import time
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from newspaper import Article
import sys
import html2text
import xmltodict
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import urllib

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }
plants_df = pd.DataFrame()
pic_searches = ['blue+marble']
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for pic_search in pic_searches:
    url = str(r'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo|categories&+\   generator=search&gsrsearch=File:') + str(pic_search) + str('&format=jsonfm&origin=*&   + \ iiprop=extmetadata&iiextmetadatafilter=ImageDescription|ObjectName') + \
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 's2'})
    lines = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
    new_list = [item.replace('"', '') for item in lines]
    new_list2 = [x for x in new_list if x.startswith('File')]
    new_list3 = [x[5:] for x in new_list2]
    new_list4 = [x.replace(' ','_') for x in new_list3]
    print(new_list4)
```

I got the result ['Blue_Marble_2021.png', 'Blue_Marble_2022.jpg', 'Blue_Marble_Comparsion.png', 'Blue_Marble_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg', 'Blue_Marble_Western_Hemisphere.jpg', 'Blue_Marble_transparent.png', 'The_Blue_Marble.jpg', 'The_Blue_Marble_(5052124705).jpg', 'The_Blue_Marble_White_Balancing.jpg', 'The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg']. But this is only 10 file names. When I type blue marble into wikimedia commons image search, hundreds of results come up. How can I get all the image file names?

Comment: You should know you can get data from the API in JSON format.
Also, likely, the API paginates the results and has an additional response parameter that contains the URL to get the next 10 or so results. You will need to have a loop that accesses each successive URL or write a generator for it.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki API queries are paginated.  This means that each API call will return a maximum number of results, and you will need to include additional parameters in subsequent requests in order to retrieve the remaining results.

The official documentation [has an example](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/API:Query#Example_4:_Continuing_queries) that demonstrates how to submit the continuation requests.

Since you are already importing `requests`, I would suggest using that library instead of `urllib.request.urlopen` for this.  You definitely should not be using BeautifulSoup to parse these responses - you can specify `format=json` and use json instead.

It will be easier to handle the continuation requests if you use a dictionary for the query params instead of manually crafting a string.

Example using Requests:

```py
def get_image_names(pic_search):
    session = requests.Session()
    url = 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php'
    params = {
        'action': 'query',
        'prop': 'imageinfo|categories',
        'generator': 'search',
        'gsrsearch': f'File:{pic_search}',
        'format': 'json',
        'origin': '*',
        'iiprop': 'extmetadata',
        'iiextmetadatafilter': 'ImageDescription|ObjectName',
        'formatversion': 2,  # only if the target wiki is running mediawiki 1.25 or above
    }
    resp = session.get(url, params=params).json()
    names =  [page['title'] for page in resp['query']['pages']]
    continue_params = resp.get('continue')
    while continue_params:
        params.update(continue_params)
        resp = session.get(url, params=params).json()
        names.extend(page['title'] for page in resp['query']['pages'])
        continue_params = resp.get('continue')
    return names
```

Comment: Thanks dskrypa. This is a pretty good answer, but it seems to return more than I expected. I tried a couple searches, and it looks like some pdf file names that are not images are included in the return list. Do you know why this is? Thanks again.

Comment: It's most likely due to a query that matches too many results.  In my own code, I usually use `prop=images` with one or more page titles, then `prop=imageinfo` with `iiprop=url` to get the URLs for the image titles discovered via the first query (or chain them together with `prop=imageinfo` and `generator=images`).  I do not regularly use `iiprop=extmetadata` or search by file name.